# C# Linq-to-sql error when using stored procedure to backup database

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I'm working with a C# and Linq-to-SQL application against a SQL Server 2008 database file. My database is not inside SQL Server, but inside my project folder.

My connection string is

```
<add name="WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Settings.OpticaConnectionString"
        connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|  \Optica.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I'm using windows authentication to access SQL Server from C#, and the `.mdf` file is copied to the output folder each time the application is run.

I have a stored procedure to back up the database. Executing the procedure within SQL Server completes successfully, but when I try to call this procedure from C# the following error occurs

> Database 'optica.mdf' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly. BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

That's though the database name `optica.mdf` is not even a parameter for the procedure.

I found a similar topic but it discusses executing the SQL code immediately from the C# linq which is not my case.

Here is my stored procedure

```
USE [OPTICA.MDF]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER proc [dbo].[Sp_OpticaDatabaseBackup]
    @Path varchar(1024),
as
Begin       
    DECLARE @fileName VARCHAR(256) -- file name for backup
    DECLARE @fileDate VARCHAR(20) -- used for file name 

    SELECT @fileDate = replace(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),GETDATE(),126),':','-')

    SET @fileName = @Path + 'Pts_' + @fileDate + '.BAK' 

    BACKUP DATABASE [optica.mdf] TO DISK = @fileName
End
```

Here is the C# linq calling piece of code
    public int backupDatabase(string path)
            {
                int res = -1;
                DataClasses1DataContext dc = new DataClasses1DataContext();
                try
                {
                    dc.Sp_OpticaDatabaseBackup(path);
                    res = 1;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

```
            }
            return res;
        }
```

and here is where the exception exactly happens

```
[Function(Name="dbo.Sp_OpticaDatabaseBackup")]
        public int Sp_OpticaDatabaseBackup([Parameter(Name="Path",   DbType="VarChar(1024)")] string path, [Parameter(Name="DB", DbType="VarChar(1024)")] string dB)
    {
        IExecuteResult result = this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())), path, dB);
        return ((int)(result.ReturnValue));
    }
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What has LINQ2SQL to do with you passing in the wrong name? The error message is totaly clear, is it not? YOu pass in a file name, not a database name.

Comment: It seems that you didn't read the question carefully, dude this stored procedure is properly working when executing it inside SQL Server, I'm not even passing the name to the procedure.

Comment: If you have a "free-floating" `.mdf` file (IMHO, this is a flawed, crappy approach to begin with....) - then you **cannot** use the `BACKUP DATABASE` command - this command **ONLY** works against databases that are **on the server**

Comment: It seems that this is the problem, but how to to use a database that is on the SQL Server instead this "free-floating" one? In my C# I cannot select an SQL Server db, I only can select a file. Thanks